# Parse columns and explode multiple columns in to one long column

Tags: microsoft-excel

Apologies for my title-I couldn't figure out a good way to say what I'm needing to do.  A picture is probably easiest.  On the left is what I have and on the right is what I need:
[image]

I need to add all these names to a database and is a person belongs to multiple ID# then they have to get put in once for each ID.

So, I think the steps I need to do are search each row and if that row has more than one ID# then duplicate that row and copy all but the last ID number.  That should be able to iterate through a loop.  Then once that's done, I could easily just merge all the empty cells in to a single column?  I'm pretty new to VBA, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Where `Bob=3` is taken from?

Comment: @Akina thanks for catching that.  It was just a mistake I made here in my mockup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```vb
Public Function GatherData(src As Range) As Variant
Dim tmp()
Dim temp()
ReDim temp(1 To 2, 1 To 1)
tmp = src.Value
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
For i = LBound(tmp, 1) + 1 To UBound(tmp, 1)
    For j = LBound(tmp, 2) + 1 To UBound(tmp, 2)
        If tmp(i, j) > "" Then
            temp(1, UBound(temp, 2)) = tmp(i, 1)
            temp(2, UBound(temp, 2)) = tmp(i, j)
            ReDim Preserve temp(1 To 2, 1 To (UBound(temp, 2) + 1))
        End If
    Next j
Next i
ReDim Preserve temp(1 To 2, 1 To (UBound(temp, 2) - 1))
GatherData = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(temp)
End Function
```

[image]

The formula is inserted as array formula (Ctrl-Shift-Enter).

If destination range is longer then needed for the result then the rest is filled with N/A. If it is shorter then the rest of values will be lost without any notice.

Comment: I've been trying to get this to work, but I'm not having any luck.  Im on a mac, and I've never used array formulas.  Ctrl-Shift-Enter seems to not do anything on a mac.  I've been googling but haven't found the workaround yet.

Comment: Got it.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use VBA, you can try to use Power Query to get the result:

1. Select the **Range**- go to **Data**- **From Table/Range**- open **Power Query Editor**:
   [image]
2. Select **ID1, ID2, ID3, ID4** columns- go to **Transform** tab- Select **Unpivot columns**- Remove **Attribute** column- **Close and Load**:

[image]